# How to delete or skip multiline string in a file using batch files

Tags: string, batch-file, skip, multilinestring

Ex-
Input file-File1.txt contains-

```
multiline

String

Mango

Orange

String

Orange
```

then out put should be in File2.txt-

```
multiline,

Mango
```

Comment: Input file-File1.txt contains-

Comment: Try to explain that better ! You want to delete the string `Multiline` and in your `ouput.txt` you have `multiline`. ??????

Comment: There are not such a "multiline string" in a text file. A text file is comprised of several, individual lines. Please, explain the method you want to follow in order to eliminate certain lines...

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET "prevline="
(
  FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('type q22913138.txt^|sort') DO (
  IF DEFINED prevline IF "%%a"=="!prevline!" ECHO(%%a
  SET "prevline=%%a"
 )
)>tempfile.txt
type q22913138.txt|FINDSTR /v /i /x /g:tempfile.txt >newfile.txt
DEL tempfile.txt 2>nul

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q22913138.txt` containing your data for my testing.
Produces newfile.txt

---

I've made some minor adjustments.

The problem appears to be that your data file has no newline after the last `Orange`. Unfortunately, it's very difficult to see precisely what the format is on a text post.

Comment: I have tried your code but still it is not giving proper output to me.
the output of your above code is-
multiline
Mango
Orange--> but orange should not be there..
I think something wrong in script.

Comment: I want to delete all occurence of a string which exist more than one time in my txt file...
file1.txt contains-
Ram
shyam
Ravi
Ravi
Ravi
Ram

then output should be in another file file2.txt
Shayam because its occurence is only one not more than that.

Comment: Is there any optimize way to print out the string which exist more than one times in your file with the number of occurence-
input file--file1.txt
Ram
Ram
sita
Ram
output should be--Ram occour 3 times.

Comment: the above code is working fine..can you please let tell me form where you have learnt the batch scripting.?? i am begginer i want to expert in that.

Comment: Practice, practice and practice - over more than 30 years.

Answer (score 0):

for every word in file1 (count occurence of this word and if only one (write to file2)):

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in ("file1.txt") do (
 for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%n in ('find /c "%%i" "file1.txt"') do (
  if %%n equ 1 echo %%i >>"file2.txt"
 )
)
```

**edit:** ("Is there any optimize way to print out the string which exist more than one times in your file with the number of occurence- input file--file1.txt "

```
@echo off
echo.>file2.txt
for /f "delims=" %%i in (file1.txt) do (
 for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%n in ('find /c "%%i" "file1.txt"') do (
  if %%n equ 1 ( 
   rem echo %%i >>"file2.txt"
  ) else ( 
   find "%%i" "file2.txt">nul ||echo %%i occures %%n times >>"file2.txt"
  )
 )
)
```

Comment: But the above code also printing the string which has one occurence .
that should not be there.please check it once.it should print only
those string which has more than one occourence.